# Как исправить ошибку Array to string conversion

Tags: php

```
for($j=0;$j<strlen($kluch);$j++){
    $shifr[$j]=$tekst[$j] ^ $kluch[$j];
    echo $shifr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Array to string conversion

переводится как

> Преобразование массива в строку

массив - это не строка и не число. Echo - для строк и чисел. Для вывода структуры массива есть другие функции. Самый простой вариант

```
print_r($shifr);
```

Узнать какого типа переменная можно так

```
var_dump($shifr);
```