# Подскажите где ошибка пожалуйста?

Tags: php

```html
<?php

$a = [
 "Россия" => ["Русский", "Львов"],
 "Беларусь" => ["Белорусский"], 
 "Киев" => ["Украинский"],
 "Финляндия" => ["Финский"]
 ];

foreach($a as $i => $b){
 echo "$i - $b\"<br>\""; // Ошибка: Array to string conversion
 foreach($b as $c){
  echo "$c\"<br>\"";
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что здесь есть ошибка?

Comment: @andreymal он это чувствует

Comment: @ andreymal Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Users\AZ\Desktop\php\htdocs\mysite\index.php on line 172 вот почему

Comment: и какая же это строчка, с номером 172? (я Вам сейчас минус поставлю)

Comment: @Igor вам настолько лень код запустить?)

Comment: @andreymal уверяю Вас, я много раз нажимал кнопку "Выполнить код" в вопросе, но ошибку, про которую пишет автор, не получил

Comment: @Igor  закрывающая  скобка в 2 цикле тут номер 172

Comment: @Igor прикидываемся дурачком? Ну окей, как хотите

Comment: @ andreymal  не обращайте внимания это просто бородатый программист

Comment: @xes тем не менее вы оформили вопрос всё же плохо, в показанном вами коде меньше чем 172 строчки, и сниппеты вообще-то не предназначены для помещения в них php-кода

Comment: @andreymal :((((

Comment: Ну и вообще возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как исправить ошибку Array to string conversion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899136/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-array-to-string-conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в переменной `$b` находится массив, по этому и ошибка. Вы пытаетесь привести массив к строке. На сколько я понял вы хотите сделать следующее:

```
foreach($a as $i => $b){
        foreach($b as $c){
            echo "$i - $c <br>";
        }
    }
```

Вывод:

```
Россия - Русский 
Россия - Львов 
Беларусь - Белорусский 
Киев - Украинский 
Финляндия - Финский
```

Comment: хочу узнать как выводить 2 мерные массивы

Comment: @xes какой результат вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: @xes ваш код из вопроса его успешно выводит, непонятно в чём проблема

Comment: @Anton Kucenko Россия - Русский, Львов

Comment: @xes ваш код его почти так и выводит